# .net c# - Create multiple copies of a file each named according to the results of a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, file, copy

I have a working knowledge of using c# (primarily web development), but limited experience.  I have the need to generate multiple copies of an existing XML file on a regular basis with unique names.  My idea is to have the default file with a static name (e.g. directory.xml) sitting in a folder and to make copies of the file in the same folder but with each of the names returned from a SQL query (single column such as "filename" which will contain unique MAC address values).  I will also need to prepend some static text.  So, if my SQL query returns 1, 2, 3 then I should end up with 4 files in my folder: directory.xml, directory_1.xml, directory_2.xml, directory_3.xml.

I'm needing to do this to generate the individual directory files for each phone in my voip system.  When employees change, I have to update each and every phone's directory which is uniquely named by its MAC address.

Comment: That all sounds logical, what have you tried? Do you have some code that doesn't work?

Comment: interesting. was there a question?

Comment: Well, I guess literally there was not a question but it was implied . . . How do I write a script to read values from a table and then create copies of a file and name them according to these values?

My project is actually a 2-parter, and I'm currently still working on the first part of generating the original directly.xml file that in turn will be copied.  I think I know how to achieve the first part and when I have an opportunity I will work on the second part with the suggestion given

Answer (score 0):

The System.IO.File class has a [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. If you've already generated the unique name, then it seems that the File.Copy() will be enough to create the new "directory.xml" file.

Comment: Okay, I've written a script that uses a sqldatareader then performs a file.copy.  However, when testing from Visual Studio and launching the app there (ctrl-F5) when I execute the page I get an error stating that I do not have permissions to access the filename that I am writing and no files appear.  In other words, it appears like thinks are working but it won't write the file due to some permissions.  I've Googled but not been able to find a resolution.  Is this a development environment issue, and will file.copy work in this environment?

Comment: That is hard to answer. Check your filename and path. Are you writing to a server or network share? [UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/user-account-control) may be involved if you are in the Administrators group. Try running the *.exe from your Debug or Release folder. If the exception happens, try running as Administrator.